# How (if possible) can this SAP Smartforms template be drawn?

Tags: layout, document, abap, sap-smart-forms

Is it possible to split a template like below image?

[image]

If it is, may I get some instructions on how to do it please? I've only managed to create the 3 frames in a configuration that is basically rotated with 90 (or 270) degrees from this one.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is possible to simply place three windows onto a page, so maybe I got your question wrong?

Comment: Although I know about the solution where i can place 3 windows (though 2 are enough) on the same page, I wanted to first see if this can't be achieved using just one template.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realize that "template" is a technical term in this case. (I ususally logon to the systems in German...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. [Check the online documentation](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/en/90/1d493d331311d5b696006094192fe3/frameset.htm):

> [...] to create a template like the one below, you **cannot** use the template concept of Smart Forms: [...] The cells of the colored part cover several lines. [...]

The linked article also contains an example on how to split the contents into separate windows.